# AzCopy Azure Storage NodeJs

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-storage, azcopy

I have a page developed in NodeJs and I want to pass a file.txt from my local to my storage account using azcopy-node.The code I currently have is as follows:

```
const { AzCopy } = require("@azure-tools/azcopy-node");

const azCopy = new AzCopy({
    accountName: "myaccount",
    accountKey: "mykey",
});

// Copy a local file to a storage account
azCopy.copy(__dirname + "/../../auto_load_event/1239.txt", "https://mystorage.blob.core.windows.net/container/1239.txt");
```

The problem I have is that when running it tells me that azcopy is not a constructor, and when I see the documentation of this link: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@azure-tools/azcopy-node I tried the code shown as an example and it does not work for me either, the error that shows me with this code is:

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'fromTo')
at AzCopyClient.copy (D:\WebApp\node_modules\@azure-tools\azcopy-node\dist\src\AzCopyClient.js:105:80)
at Object.redirectFILE (D:\WebApp\src\security\Centinela\redireccion_nativo.js:11:30)
at Object.<anonymous> (D:\WebApp\src\index.js:97:5)
at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1254:14)
at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1308:10)
at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1117:32)
at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:958:12)
at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
at node:internal/main/run_main_module:23:47
```

I would like to be able to pass .TXT files from my local to my storage_account using Azcopy or if you know a better way to transfer files I thank you for sharing the information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If you know a better way to transfer files I thank you for sharing the information

You can try with **`@azure/storage-blob`** package to copy a file from local to Azure blob storage.

**Code:**

```
const { BlobServiceClient } = require("@azure/storage-blob");
const fs = require("fs");

async function uploadFileToBlobStorage() {
  const connectionString = "<your-storage connection string>";
  const containerName = "<container name>";
  const blobName = "sample.txt";
  const filePath = "C:\\Users\\v-xxx\\xxx\\xxx\\file.txt";

  const blobServiceClient = BlobServiceClient.fromConnectionString(connectionString);
  const containerClient = blobServiceClient.getContainerClient(containerName);
  const blockBlobClient = containerClient.getBlockBlobClient(blobName);

  const uploadOptions = {
    bufferSize: 4 * 1024 * 1024, 
    maxBuffers: 20
  };

  const stream = fs.createReadStream(filePath);
  const uploadResult = await blockBlobClient.uploadStream(stream, uploadOptions.bufferSize, uploadOptions.maxBuffers);

  console.log("Upload successful");
}

uploadFileToBlobStorage();
```

**Output:**

[image]

**Reference:**

[Upload a blob with JavaScript - Azure Storage | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blob-upload-javascript)

Comment: Thanks for the information. See, if you are using a SAS_Token, should you place it in the "connectionString" variable?

Comment: Connecting strings are different you can get that from  `portal -> storage account -> access key -> connection string ` https://i.imgur.com/yKRryQy.png

Comment: Yes, but in this case you could modify the code to use the SAS_Token?

Comment: So you need my code with sas token right?.